# Cyclic subgroups of finite $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-Dedekind $p$-group with non-cyclic center, where $p$ is an odd prime.
By $[\langle x\rangle]_G=\{g^{-1}\langle x\rangle g\ |\ g\in G\},$
 I mean the conjugacy class of the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ of $G$ and 
 $U=\{[\langle x\rangle]_G\ |\ \langle x\rangle\ntrianglelefteq  G\}$ is the set of all 
conjugacy classes of non-normal  cyclic subgroups of $G$.
Also $\Omega_1(G)$  denotes the subgroup generated by all elements of $G$ of order at most $p$.
Let $z\in \Omega_1(Z(G))\setminus\{1\}$ and  consider the following subsets of $U$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&U_1=\{[\langle x\rangle]_G\in U\ |\ \langle z\rangle\not\leq \langle x\rangle,
 \ \ [\langle x\rangle]_G=\{ \langle xz^i\rangle\ |\ 0\leq i\leq p-1\}\}\\
&&U_2 =\{[\langle x\rangle]_G\in U\ |\ \langle z\rangle\not\leq \langle x\rangle,\ \ 
 [\langle x\rangle]_G\cap\{ \langle xz^i\rangle\ |\ 1\leq i\leq p-1\}=\phi\}
\end{eqnarray*}

I want  to give an affirmative or negative answer to the follwing question

Question: If for each $z\in \Omega_1(Z(G))\setminus\{1\}$, we have $U_1=U_2=\phi$ , then is 
 $\mbox{exp}(Z(G))=p$ and $G^{\prime}$ an elementary abelian $p$-group?

I could not find any counter example but in the following minor case I 
know the answer to the first part of the Question  is yes,

Let all non-normal  subgroups of $G$ be  cyclic  and let there exists an element 
$x\in \Omega_1(G)\setminus Z(G)$. In the contrary case, if there exists $z\in Z(G)$ such that $o(z)>p$,
 then $\Omega_1(\langle x,z\rangle)\cong C_p\times C_p$ and
by assumption $\Omega_1(\langle x,z\rangle)\lhd G$. Now since $\langle x\rangle\leq \Omega_1(\langle x,z\rangle)$,
it follows that $[\langle x\rangle]_G\in U_1$,  which is a contradiction.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.